# Testing using Jersey framework with reporting using Extentreports

Tags: java, unit-testing, reporting, jersey-2.0, extentreports

I am new to testing, need to report testing results using extentreports,

below is the code for testing:

```
public ExtentReports reports;
public ExtentTest logger;

public ModelTests() {
    reports = new ExtentReports("acceptanceTest\\reports\\Report.html");
}

@Test
public void searchModelTest() throws JSONException, URISyntaxException {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = searchModel();                
    logger = reports.startTest("Test");
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Success");
    assertEquals("SOLAR SLEEVE 2014", jsonResponse.getString("modelName"));
    logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failure");
    reports.endTest(logger);
}
```

I do not see any report getting generated.

Will extentreport work with jersey framework, I have seen selenium examples.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing `reports.flush()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a checklist that you should follow:

1. Create a new instance of ExtentReports.

   > ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports(file-path, replaceExisting);
2. Name and describe the instance via the startTest method. Keep in mind, you are now creating a new instance of ExtentTest.

   > ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Test Name", "Sample description");
3. Log your results against your ExtentTest instance.

   > test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Step details");
4. End your test.

   > extent.endTest(test);
5. Finally write everything to your document

   > extent.flush();

Also, here is the documentation specifically for those implementing via Maven.

[ExtentReports | Maven Documentation](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/version2/docs.html#maven)

...

Answer (score 0):

Review the extentreport's documentation on annotations.

Also, is this a maven project? Maven will help with the overall organization of your testing project.

Comment: Yes, this is a Maven project. I am not able to find documentation annotations can you please give some links. Also I do not see the report itself, can junit testing be used for extentreport generation or is it just Selenium testing.